# MySQL - Select rows where a column matches an entry anywhere linked list

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

Getting many customer complaints for a slow search engine- and rightfully so.

I've got a database search engine and I am a little stumped on how to make this last part of the search I need run with good performance.  If the user searches on certain words, it can take up to a minute to execute.

To explain my setup; I have a table called **my_table** with my searchable item entries.  These items have a column called **linked_list** which contains a pointer to the **id** (primary index) into the table **linked_list**.

**linked_list** has columns **id**, **parent**, **value**

Rows in **my_table** can point to any **id** in **linked_list**, and at any point inside of a particular list. (no list is more than 7 links deep)

I need to allow the user to search on **value** in **linked_list**.  So the way I am currently doing this is by first searching **linked_list** for the user's query, like this:

```
SELECT id FROM linked_list WHERE value LIKE '%query%'
```

After I get all results, I turn them into an array of **id** with php, like this: {2516,8645,235,4,665,...}

Then I give EACH of these array items its own "WHERE .. IN .." as below, and OR them together.

As you can imagine, if I have more than 4 matches of **value** inside of **linked_list**, searching becomes unreasonable.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE 
    (((1108 in (linked_list_id,
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = linked_list_id), 
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent )))) 
OR ((2791 in (linked_list_id,
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = linked_list_id), 
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent )))) 
....
```

Before you tell me "just store the entire linked list in my_table", that is not reasonable.  linked_list may change and it will become a maintenance nightmare.

I've thought about using Union, Join, HAVING .. IN .., but nothing is working.  I'll be grateful to anyone who can help me with this problem!  Thank you!

--- Edit ---
Here is some sample data.

### **my_table**

```
  id  |  linked_list_id
--------------------
   1  |    1000
   2  |    1050
   3  |    1234
   4  |    1001
   5  |    1000
   6  |    1600
```

### **linked_list**

```
  id  |  parent   |   value   |
--------------------------------
1000  |     0     |     A     |     (This is the root of one linked list)
1001  |    1000   |     B     |
1050  |    1600   |     C     |
1234  |     0     |     D     |     (This is the root of another linked list)
1500  |    1000   |     E     |
1600  |    1001   |     AA    |
```

(So the structure of this data is:)

```
1050 -> 1600 -> 1001 -> 1000 -> 0
                1500 ---^       |
                        1234 ---^
```

Note: the longest linked list I have is 7 nodes deep.  This is constrained by the application so they likely won't ever go past 7 nodes deep.

So if I search for

```
SELECT id FROM linked_list WHERE value LIKE '%A%'
```

I get

```
{1000,1600}
```

And then when I run the long query, it looks like this:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table
WHERE 
    (((1000 in (linked_list_id,
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = linked_list_id), 
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent )))) 
OR ((1600 in (linked_list_id,
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = linked_list_id), 
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent ),
    (SELECT @last_parent:=`parent` FROM `linked_list` WHERE `id` = @last_parent )))) 
....
```

I would expect the returned result to be

```
{1,2,4,5,6}
```

since each of those rows contain %A% somewhere in their linked list.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: can you give some sample data in table?

Answer (score 1):

So I wound up resolving this myself.

For anyone who this might help, I did the following.

1) I first query **linked_list** for any matches of %query% and write the results into an array of IDs, like (1,2,3,4)

2) I recursively query **linked_list** to get all CHILDREN whose parents are in the array of IDs above, appending results to the array of IDs.

3) Then in my main **my_table** search query, I simply say

```
'... HAVING `linked_list_id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...)'
```